# Existence of polynomial p with real coefficients such that p(n) is prime if and only if n is palindrome

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Does there exist any polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $p(n)$ is a prime number if and only if $n$ is a palindrome number ?
($n$ must be a positive palindrome number to give $p(n)$ a prime number).

Comment: Palindromes have a kind of some pattern and hence if the result of the above question is true then probably we have a good result. So this was the motivation behind this. But also saying that I may be ignorant of any known result related or sort of implying this.

Comment: I doubt it.  Let q be a prime with q=p(n) and n a palindrome.  I believe there are infinitely many larger palindromes m with m - n a multiple of q.  If so, then either p(m) is q and p is constant, or p(m) is a proper multiple of q for at least one such m. Gerhard "Possibly Excepting Base Plus One" Paseman, 2017.07.18.

Comment: It would violate the Bateman-Horn conjecture, so probably no.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch I kind of was thinking something like this may happen as a consequence or so, but wasn't at all sure of what I was thinking. So I forbid myself from writing it. Looks like you thought nearly same and thus now  think I am safe in believing that my thoughts weren't a glitch !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such non-constant polynomial, even if we only assume that $p(10^m+1)$ is prime for $m=0,1,\dots$. Using this weaker condition for $m=0,1,\dots,\deg p$, we infer that $p(x)$ has rational coefficients. Let $N$ be a common denominator of the coefficients, and write it as $N=2^r5^sM$ with $(M,10)=1$. Fix $k\geq\max(r,s)$ such that the prime $K:=p(10^k+1)$ exceeds $10$. Now let $\ell\geq k$ be arbitrary with $\phi(MK)\mid\ell-k$. Then $NK\mid 10^kMK\mid 10^\ell-10^k$, hence $K\mid p(10^\ell+1)-p(10^k+1)$. In other words, $K\mid p(10^\ell+1)$, i.e., $K=p(10^\ell+1)$. So $p(10^\ell+1)$ equals $K$ for infinitely many integers $\ell\geq 0$, contradiction.

Comment: Very nice work @(GH from MO). Also shows some nice motivation.